# Java: how to validate list of object against schema before saving it in database?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, validation, jpa

Table:

- Employee `{ emp_id(len 5), Name(len 45), City(Len 30) }`
- Salary `{ Id (len 5), Emp_id(len 5), Amount(len 8) }`

I have Entity class of both the tables in Java generated by hibernate and I need to bulk insert data (From Excel sheet) into the database and before inserting I want to validate the whole data set (like has attribute length as allowed by the Database, not null constraint etc) against database constraint.

What will be the best/optimal way of doing so?

Comment: what have you done so far.  Have you even bothered to search for a simple phrase like `hibernate validate`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Hibernate Validator (http://hibernate.org/validator/).

You should be able to annotate your entities with whatever validation rules you need.

Comment: If you don't like this answer, please leave a comment as to why.

Comment: Not the downvoter but answering questions where the OP has done no research and provided no code is usually frowned upon.  As per my original comment, if the OP had done a simple search such as `hibernate validate` he would have found your link at the very top.

Comment: Thanks.  Learned something new today.